# What is the difference between $("<tag></tag>") and $('<tag>')?

Tags: jquery

From the context of the code I am reading, it seems like `$("<tag></tag>")` creates a tag, where as `$('<tag>')` is a selector that searches for a tag.  What's going on here?  Actually I might not have the syntax of the second one right, but I'm sure I've done `$('idName')` like this before.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `$("<tag></tag>")` and `$("<tag>")` and `$("<tag />")` is personal style/preference (unless you're using IE, apparently. see comment). All three will use the native `createElement()` method to create a now DOM element. If the tags have parameters it will parse them create the element by some other means.

More info on creating things here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

To select elements by id, you'd use `$("#idName")`.

To select existing elements by tag name, `$("tag")`.

To select existing elements by class name, `$(".className")`.

More info on selecting things here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: Ryan, the difference is not just personal preference but can actually cause problems in IE if you use $("<tag>"). At least according to core jQuery team member Cody Lindley in his book jQuery Enlightenment.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. One more reason to be glad I can generally ignore IE on internal apps.

Answer (score 2):

Create an element:

```
$("<div>Hello</div>").appendTo("body"); // <body><div>Hello</div></body>
```

Select the DIVs:

```
$("div").addClass("myClass"); // <div></div> -> <div class='myClass'></div>
```

Select an element by its `ID`:

```
$("#myDiv"); // selects <div id='myDiv'>Hello World</div>
```

And by its `class`:

```
$(".myDiv"); // selects <div class='myDiv'>Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between double quote and single quote.

Jonathan gave you a good example of the different between selector and and DOM element creation. It can be done with this too:

Create an element:

```
$('<div></div>');
$("<div class='class1'></div>");
$('<div attrib="val"></div>');
```

Select the DIVs

```
$('div');
```

However `$('<tag>')` DOES NOT select a tag. Refer to the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).